# In Numbers, how can I find all references to a cells?

Tags: macos, numbers

I got `B3=B2÷B1` and when I click `B3` the B2 and B1 get highlighted with the colours you see.

I want `B3` to be highlighted when I click on either `B2` or `B1`.

[image: Clicking on a cell with a Formula highlights its input cells]

My search engine and StackOverflow did not return results for for "macOS numbers find cells referencing a given cell", "find cell references"; nor the Number's manual.

Is this at all possible?

Bonus question: how to update all references to a cell to point to another cell?